# calling dropdown functions javascript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a drop down menu that displays different divs based on the selected option.

```
<select id='building-type'>  
                            <option disabled selected value> -- select an option -- </option>
                            <option id="residential" value="residential" [...]>Residential</option>
                            <option id="commercial" value="commercial " [...]>Commercial</option>
                            <option id="corporate" value="corporate" [...]>Corporate</option>
                            <option id="hybrid" value="hybrid" [...]>Hybrid</option>
        
                        </select>
```

In those divs I call my function elevatorCalc() like so.

```
<div class="col-md-4" id="number-of-apartments">
                                <label for="residential_apartments">Number of apartments *</label>
                                <input onchange="elevatorCalc()" required type="number" class="form-control" id="resinput_number-of-apartments">
                            </div>
```

The function elevatorCalc() worked with radio buttons but when I switched it to a dropdown it stopped working.

this is my function

```
  function elevatorCalc() {
        const floors = document.getElementById("resinput_number-of-floors");
        if (document.getElementById("commercial").checked == true) {
          commercial(); 
        } else if (document.getElementById("residential").checked == true && parseInt(floors.value) <= 20) {
          residential();
        } else if (document.getElementById("residential").checked == true && parseInt(floors.value) > 20) {
          residential20();
        } else if (document.getElementById("corporate").checked == true) {
          corpo();
        } else if (document.getElementById("hybrid").checked == true) {
          hybrid();
        }   
  }
```

My guess was that the problem came from .checked but I really don't know.

Answer (score 0):

You should get the selected value like this:

```
let value = document.getElementById('building-type').value;
```

for the logic:

```
switch(value) {
    case 'residential':
        residential();
        break;
    case 'corporate':
        corpo();
    ...
```